# How to get variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have a variable $button with value of 85.25 and I want to get this value in other variable.

I tried like below but not getting variable from $button

```
$button = '85.25';

$orderAmount = $button;
```

The goal is when I print $orderAmount it should print **85.25**

I am new to php, sorry for my question I know this is basics.

Comment: Can you post the full code, and why you need `$orderAmount = $GLOBALS['$button'];` to get the variable if the first exist?

Comment: `$GLOBALS['$button']` is incorrect, variables in single quotes are literal. I also dont understand why you'd need this though.

Comment: other variable or other page ?

Comment: @chris85 I have updated question

Comment: [It works fine for me.](https://eval.in/private/0116101128f3a6)

Comment: Can you add more code to the question? Is this in a function?

Comment: Put more code in question and tell us what you're getting when doing var_dump($orderAmount);

Answer (score 0):

```
$button = 85.25;

echo $orderAmount = $button;
```